# Field Authorization level with Postgraphile

Tags: graphql, postgraphile

Currently, I'm working with Postgraphile and I need to enforce permissions at data/field level.

For example, I have a **carmodel** table, with my query is something like:

```
{
   carmodel
      {  
         id
         name
         description
      }
}
```

Well, in this table I have ids (1 = AUDI, 2 = GM, 3 = BMW)
The current user (on roles/claims) has permission only to see (1=AUDI/3=BMW)

There is a way to enforce permissions based on field data? And return only data filtered on the user permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; row-level security can define this declaratively. Something like:

```sql
create policy audi_bmw on carmodel for select using (
  id in (1, 3)
);
```

I'm guessing this permission comes from another table though; so it might be more like:

```sql
create policy audi_bmw on carmodel for select using (
  id in (
    select car_model_id
    from user_carmodel_permissions
    where user_id = current_user_id()
  )
);
```

assuming you already have a `current_user_id` function, something like:

```sql
create function current_user_id() returns int as $$
  select nullif(current_setting('jwt.claims.user_id', true), '')::int;
$$ language sql stable;
```

Check out [our row level security cheatsheet](https://learn.graphile.org/docs/PostgreSQL_Row_Level_Security_Infosheet.pdf).